# while loop is only printing one time instead of for the entire loop

Tags: java, printing, while-loop

I have a program in which I use a while loop to print both to the console and to a html file. However even though it prints to the console the program will only print the final line to the html file.  Here is the code for my loop which is supposed to print the information extracted from a text file for the lines 9 to 16.

```
  //read the txt file
Path objPath = Paths.get("dirsize.txt");  
if (Files.exists(objPath))
{

    File objFile = objPath.toFile();
  try(BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                          new FileReader(objFile)))
   {
    String line = in.readLine();
    int lineNum = 1;
    //extract the month
    String monthSubstring = line.substring(25,27);
    month = Integer.parseInt(monthSubstring) -1 ;
    //extact the year
    String yearSubstring = line.substring(31,35);
    year = (Integer.parseInt(yearSubstring));
    //extract the date
    String daySubstring = line.substring(28,30);
    day = Integer.parseInt(daySubstring);
     PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter (new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("Output.html")));
    while(line != null)
    {
      line = in.readLine();
      lineNum ++;
      if (lineNum == 3)
       {
           //extract the hour
            String hourSubstring = line.substring(21,23);
             hour = Integer.parseInt(hourSubstring); 
            //extract the minute
            String minuteSubstring = line.substring(24,26);
             minute = Integer.parseInt(minuteSubstring);
            //extract the second
            String secondSubstring = line.substring(27,29);
            second= Integer.parseInt(secondSubstring);
           }
      if(lineNum ==5)
       {
            //Extract the branch
            strBranch = line.substring(22, 27);        
       }        
      if (lineNum == 6)
      {
             //Extract the computer
             strCPU = line.substring(26,32);
      }   
     if (lineNum >= 9 && lineNum <= 16)
      {
          //call the MyDirectory methods to get the files name,size and number of files
          MyDirectory directory = new MyDirectory(line);
          fileName = directory.getName();
          fileSize = directory.getsize();
          fileNum = directory.getNum();
          //create the dteDate calender
          GregorianCalendar dteDate = new GregorianCalendar(year, month, day, hour, minute, second);
          //fromat the date
          SimpleDateFormat strDate = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, yyyy h:m");
        //Write the data to the file
         out.println((strBranch + "; " +
                  strCPU + "; "  + 
                  strDate.format(dteDate.getTime())) + "; " +
                  fileName + "; " +
                  fileSize + "; " + 
                  fileNum);
         //create the necessary output for the console
          System.out.println((strBranch + "; " +
                  strCPU + "; "  + 
                  strDate.format(dteDate.getTime())) + "; " +
                  fileName + "; " +
                  fileSize + "; " + 
                  fileNum);
        }    
       out.flush();
    }

   }   

  //catch any IOExceptions and print out e
 catch (IOException e)
  {
    System.out.println(e);  
  }

}
```

EDIT: Through advice posted in answers I now have my output for everything but im having a hard time formatting it the html file has all the lines together with no spacing I tried using "\n" at the end of my output but then my code doesn't compile because it says a null is not allowed there anyone know how to format this into lines when it wont let me put "\n" at the end of my print method?

I'm unsure if this is to much code or not enough to solve the problem and if I should add anything to my post or take anything out just let me know.

Answer (score 3):

That's pretty obvious - you create file each time your while loop iterates (see below):

```
             PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter (
                           new BufferedWriter(
                           new FileWriter("Output.html")));
        //Write the data to the file
         out.println((strBranch + "; " +
                  strCPU + "; "  + 
                  strDate.format(dteDate.getTime())) + "; " +
                  fileName + "; " +
                  fileSize + "; " + 
                  fileNum);
        //flush the data and close the output stream
         out.close();
```

You should create your file before entering while loop instead.

So your code should look something like that:

```
     PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter (new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("Output.html")));
     while(line != null)
    {
        //perform your file operations here
    }
    out.close();
```

---- edit ----

You have updated your code but it's still not ok. You close your file inside of the second loop:

```
        (...)
 while (lineNum >= 9 && lineNum <= 16)
  {
      //call the MyDirectory methods to get the files name,size and number of files
      MyDirectory directory = new MyDirectory(line);
      fileName = directory.getName();
      fileSize = directory.getsize();
      fileNum = directory.getNum();
      //create the dteDate calender
      GregorianCalendar dteDate = new GregorianCalendar(year, month, day, hour, minute, second);
      //fromat the date
      SimpleDateFormat strDate = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, yyyy h:m");
    //Write the data to the file
     out.println((strBranch + "; " +
              strCPU + "; "  + 
              strDate.format(dteDate.getTime())) + "; " +
              fileName + "; " +
              fileSize + "; " + 
              fileNum);
    //flush the data and close the output stream
     //################# YOU CLOSE YOUR FILE HERE:
     out.close();
     //create the necessary output for the console
      System.out.println((strBranch + "; " +
              strCPU + "; "  + 
              strDate.format(dteDate.getTime())) + "; " +
              fileName + "; " +
              fileSize + "; " + 
              fileNum);
     //move on in the loop so it's not infinte
      break;
   }    
}
```

When this loop iterates next time you still try to write to your file (and then close it again even though it was closed on previous iteration).

Comment: Maybe I implemented this wrong but It didn't fix my problem Ill update my code into my original post so you can see how I did it

Comment: hmm now im not getting anything at all in the html file it's completely empty ill edit my code to show what part I changed since I could have done it wrong

Comment: I moved the close operation to after the second } after then end of the loop but now my html file is empty and is not receiving any data from my print method

Comment: When I didn't have the break statement it printed out the first line forever

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28583/discussion-between-greg0ry-and-alex-chapp)

Comment: I changed my code with your advice the problem with moving the out statement further down is it doesn't see the FileWriter any more so it can't find where out is created. I changed the while statement to an if statement and removed the break line.  the Buffered writer is a request from my teacher so I need it in there and all it does is make the program buffer so its more efficient if im correct.  My html file is still blank and not getting anything written to it.  Is there some way to make my code easier for you to read?

Comment: That's your homework eh? Oh well, it's 2am in the morning where I am so I would suggest creating new project where you can test BufferedWriter on your own (just open the file, call println couple of times and close the file to confirm all lines are written). Good luck!

Comment: I never figured out how to format lines between all the data printed but I emailed my teacher and they said they didn't care if it had the lines or not since the main point of the lesson was figuring out how to read and print to text files so It was fine as is.  The solution to the problem we discussed was not closing the data stream at all but using a flush statement instead of one to flush and close it. Thank you for all the help to get that far and explaining every  step since im trying to learn I appreciated that.

Comment: As far as I remember initial problem you have had was you have been opening and closing your file inside the loop so only single line was appearing in it. Anyway - good to hear you have worked it through.

Comment: That was the initial problem and using your fix of moving the close far out meant that the data was never being written to the console because after the loop the data went away before it could be given to the console so I combined your solution with adding a out.flush line instead of out.close and it gave all the data to the console in an unformulatted manner so this fix works but it messes up the format of whatever is being printed to the file

Answer (score 0):

You see only one line in the output file because you are overwriting the file each time you write to it.

If you have to create the PrintWriter within the while(linenum >=9  && linenum <=16) loop, open the file in append mode:

**new FileWriter("Output.html", true);**

will fix your problem.

Comment: This does fix the problem of not everything writing to the file but creates the problem that everything on the file is together instead of new lines.  I tried to fix this with "\n" on the end of the out.println(Printed stuff here) but then I get the error that a void type is not allowed

Comment: Actually, you do not need to wrap a PrintWriter around BufferedWriter, BufferedWriter alone would work in your case. Just call the write() method on the BufferedWriter object and then call the newLine() method. That should fix it.

Comment: I changed my constuctor to  BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter ((new FileWriter("Output.html"))); but now the program cant find the println method for out.println

Comment: There is no println() method for BufferedWriter class. As mentioned in my comment, you should use write() method to write the contents to the file, followed by a call to newLine() method on the BufferedWriter object to make sure everything is not written to the same line. Please also mark my original response as the correct answer if it addresses your question.